# Does Breeze.js support entity data model (edm) that contains Spatial Type?

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I have an edmx which has an entity called "Address". The entity "Address" has a property called "GeoLocation" which is of type **Geography** (Spatial Type).

When I run my javascript, performing a simple query for any entity in my model, Breeze.js complains:

> Error: Unable to Recognize DataType is: Edm.Geography

Does Breeze.js support Spatial Type? Is there another way to succeed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Breeze doesn't support spatial types right now.

If you'd like to see it in a future build, please [upvote it on UserVoice](http://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3361941-support-for-spatial-types):

Comment: If you can expose the spatial data through your server-side API, you can access it with a Breeze client via AJAX call and add that data to your client-side model. The current limitation is confined to the entityManager.executeQuery. But you always have HTTP.